# How do you say you want to share something with someone?

Tags: sentence

Like this:

> 私はこの漫画と友達に共有したいです
> "I would like to share this manga with my friends"

It is okay if I use this sentence?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1) You should look carefully at the particles. The thing you are sharing is the object of the sentence. 2) I wonder what you mean by 'share'. I'm guessing you don't really want your friends to have joint ownership of your manga. Maybe you should think about using 'lend' instead?

Comment: Hello! It's not my manga, but it a manga from twitter. What I mean is, I want to share something online on the internet. And btw, should I use を instead of に？

Comment: FWIW, シェアする has become pretty common as well.  分かち合う is another verb for "share".

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> 私はこの漫画と友達に共有したいです

is not grammatical.
The thing you are sharing is the manga. This is the object of the sentence and should be marked with を.

The person you are sharing with should be marked with と. I think it is generally true that と has a mutual feel to it, whereas に is more one-directional.

So you will get:

> 私は友達と漫画を共有したいです。

Comment: Thank you very much! your answer help me a lot!